# C++ map a template derived class

Tags: c++

Hi I have a the following structures and data types:

```
enum EWorkerType
{
   WorkerType1,
   WorkerType2,
   LastWorker
};

template<class DerivedType>
struct CHandlerMethod
{
};

struct CFunctorA : public CHandlerMethod<CFunctorA>
{
};
struct CFunctorB : public CHandlerMethod<CFunctorB>
{
};

template<class TFunctor>
struct CWorkerHandler
{
    CHandlerMethod<TFunctor>* m_HandlerMethod;
};

typedef std::vector<CWorkerHandler<CFunctorA>*> WorkerA;
typedef std::vector<CWorkerHandler<CFunctorB>*> WorkerB;
```

I need a direction to create a const map between EWorkerType::WorkerType1 to WorkerA and  EWorkerType::WorkerType2 to WorkerB.

I tried this direction

```
struct WorkersMapping
{
WorkersMapping()
{
    m_WorkersMapper.insert(EWorkerType::WorkerType2, CFunctorA::value_type());
}
static std::map<EWorkerType, ???> m_WorkersMapper;
};
static WorkersMapping m_WorkersMapping;
```

Comment: Maps cannot map types, only values of some type. Still, you can use a template, if the key is a compile-time constant-expression.

Comment: ...unless the type itself is the value.  Which would be terribly confusing if that's your goal.  @Boaz, please clarify your question.

Comment: You might be looking for _type traits_. Or in this case, "_enum traits_".

Comment: @Boaz How do you want to use it? If you need to create a `CHandlerMethod<X>` based on a `EWorkerType` known at compile-time, you want to use traits, as Oktalist suggested. If this needs to be done at runtime, you might need a factory.

Comment: If `CWorkerHandler<TFunctor>` inherits from a non-template `CWorkerHandlerBase` then a factory could return a `typedef std::vector<CWorkerHandlerBase*> WorkerBase`.

Answer (score 2):

You may use something like (for compile time):

```
template <EWorkerType> struct WorkersMapping;

template <> struct WorkersMapping<WorkerType1>
{
    using type = WorkerA;
};

template <> struct WorkersMapping<WorkerType2>
{
    using type = WorkerB;
};
```

or if your `enum` values is correctly chosen, something like:

```
template <EWorkerType E> struct WorkersMapping
{
    using type = typename std::tuple_element<E, std::tuple<WorkerA, WorkerB>>::type;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap WorkerA and WorkerB into respective classes derived from a common base class, in addition to also inheriting from std::vector (multiple inheritance). Then simply define your map value as a smart pointer to the base class (or a regular pointer if you want to put the worker objects on the stack).